If there a waiter on a semaphore, why can a thread post to itself?
Here is some code I wrote to understand the semantics of semaphores:
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t sem;

void *helper(void *arg) {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        printf("helper woke up\n");
}

int main() {
        sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, helper, NULL);
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&sem);
        sem_wait(&sem);
        printf("main woke up\n");
        exit(0);
}                   

Why does this print
main woke up

rather than this?
helper woke up

If we look at the man pages, it says

If the semaphore's value consequently becomes greater than zero, then an‐
other process or thread blocked in a sem_wait(3) call will be woken up and proceed to lock the semaphore.

so why is the main thread allowed to proceed instead of the helper thread?

so why is the main thread allowed to proceed instead of the helper thread?  Why wouldn't that be true?  How do you even know the child thread even reaches sem_wait() before the main thread does?


If there a waiter on a semaphore, why can a thread post to itself?

It can't.  A thread posts to the semaphore.  It is important to understand that this is a separate matter from which thread is next to decrement the semaphore.
I guess what you really want to know is why the thread that just posted is able to decrement the semaphore again before the one already waiting -- supposing there is one -- does so.  That's a better question than I initially thought.  The basic answer is not very satisfying: your semaphore implementation allows it.
This is not uncommon.  The operational model is that posting to a locked semaphore increments it unconditionally, and wakes some number of threads that previously were blocked on the semaphore (at least one if there are any).  Any threads attempting to lock the semaphore, perhaps including some arriving contemporaneously, then contend normally for that privilege.
It is my understanding that the above is how POSIX semaphores work on Linux, which I take to be relevant because the manual excerpt you posted seems to be from the Linux manual page for sem_post().  That manual page is sloppily written, unfortunately.  It cannot be correct for the case where there is no thread waiting for the semaphore at the time of the sem_post() call, regardless of how we might try to parse the text to match actual behavior when there is a waiter. I take it to be influenced by the POSIX specification for sem_post(), possibly misinterpreted in light of Linux's actual behavior, which I now think is non-conforming.
Here's what POSIX says, in relevant part:

If the semaphore value resulting from this operation is positive, then
no threads were blocked waiting for the semaphore to become unlocked;
the semaphore value is simply incremented.
If the value of the semaphore resulting from this operation is zero,
then one of the threads blocked waiting for the semaphore shall be
allowed to return successfully from its call to sem_wait().

That affords two and only two non-error possibilities:

if there is at least one thread waiting for the semaphore at the time of the sem_post() then the semaphore remains locked (its value stays zero) and one of the waiting threads wakes and proceeds.

otherwise (no threads were waiting on the semaphore), the semaphore's value is incremented, with no other direct effect.


That is not the Linux behavior I described, nor is the behavior you observed consistent with that.
Your observed behavior is easily understandable in terms of Linux semaphore semantics. It is pretty likely that a thread that posts to the semaphore and then immediately attempts to decrement it will decrement without blocking. It is in contention for the semaphore as a thread "arriving contemporaneously", and it is already active when the semaphore becomes available.  Any threads blocked on the semaphore have to wake up, so the one that just posted is primed to win the ensuing race to acquire the semaphore.

"if there is at least one thread waiting for the semaphore at the time of the sem_post() then the semaphore remains locked (its value stays zero) and one of the waiting threads"
This is exactly the behavior that I expect after reading the POSIX spec.
However, if we look around POSIX more, there an example of a semaphore implementation that could lead to the behavior observed in Linux.
So a straight forward interpretation of the spec is incorrect, and leads to a deeper question: WHY is this behavior (new waiter wakes up before old waiters) allowed?

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/pthread_mutexattr_destroy.html

@JoshLevi, I take you to be talking about the code in the rationale.  That is "a simple counting semaphore in a mapped file that may be used by many processes", demonstrating some properties of mutexes.  It is not purported to be a conforming implementation of the POSIX semaphore API.  That is emphasized, albeit subtly, by using different names for the semaphore manipulation functions.

@JoshLevi, I maintain that the behavior you observe does not conform to POSIX.  However, we can still ask why Glibc (at least) implements the POSIX semaphore API that way.  I cannot speak authoritatively to that, but I expect that it is simpler and faster.  Also, although POSIX semaphores are not supposed to behave that way, analogous behavior is not forbidden for pthreads mutexes or Sys V semaphore sets, nor are you likely to see it in most semaphore implementations you meet.  It's a pretty unusual characteristic. [...]

[...] and because it's unusual, general semaphore-based algorithms do not depend on it.  I understand relying on the documentation, and being surprised by an unexpected result.  But you should understand that what you attempted to do was unwise in the larger scheme of things.  I would even say incorrect if it were not for the technicality that relevant documentation for the particular semaphore implementation you are using seemed to say that you could get away with it.


If there a waiter on a semaphore, why can a thread post to itself?

Because this thread received CPU time.

why is the main thread allowed to proceed instead of the helper thread?

Because the main thread received CPU time and continued operation, instead of the helper thread, which most probably did not receive CPU time and is still sleeping on the sem_wait.

instead of the helper thread, which most probably did not receive CPU time and is still sleeping on the sem_wait  If it even got that far.  There's no guarantee the helper thread has even been started by the time the main thread reaches sem_wait(), much less reached its sem_wait() call itself.

ah but that's why the sleep(1) is there, so it is guaranteed that the helper has started

sleep is not a "guarantee". It's a guess. If you want to guarantee, you would use a barrier. There is a big difference between "guarantee" and "happens".

what are the chances that in 1 second a thread might not be scheduled?

Slim. But slim is still not a guarantee.

I tried this code on my Linux and got the result like you.
But when I use gdb to debug this code step by step I find the helper woke up was printed on the terminal but the main thread will keep waiting forever.
Therefore, I think it might be an undefined behavior because the main thread would never enter the printf function and the main function would never exit. So it may involve some system mechanism strangely.
You could delete the last sem_wait(&sem); in the main function and would get the result like this.
helper woke up
main woke up

or
main woke up
helper woke up

Besides, using pthread_join() rather than sem_wait() at the end of the main function would force the main thread to wait until the end of the child thread so that the result will always print helper woke up firstly and then print main woke up.
But if you don't care about the execution order and just want to simulate the sleep and wake-up mechanism, either would be alright.

You could delete the last sem_wait(&sem); in the main function and would get the result like this If you delete sem_wait() from the main thread in the posted code, the entire process could end before the child thread even starts because main() has nothing stopping it from returning and ending the entire process.

If you do want the main thread to execute the printf statement after the end of the child thread. You could use the pthread_join to enforce the main thread wait until the end of the child thread.
